# Trouble adding a scaled down bitmap to a marker on Google maps

Tags: java, android, bitmap, google-maps-markers

My app places markers in the locations where the images retrieved from a camera were taken.
I want to display the icons for these markers as bitmaps of the images themselves.
This requires me to scale down the images or I get a `OutOfMemory` error.

Comment: Hi Joe, it will help others to answer your question if you provide a self-contained example that is easy for others to run. Otherwise it can be difficult to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(imagePath, 100, 100);
```

You are calling a custom method. decodeSampledBitmapFromFile() is not present in the BitmapFactory class. It should be like this:

```
Bitmap icon = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(imagePath, 100, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks I found the solution